# Can't get exp4j to install

Tags: java, android, git, android-studio

I'm currently writing an android application in android studio. As part of my application I would like to use the exp4j library:

```
import net.objecthunter.exp4j.Expression;
import net.objecthunter.exp4j.ExpressionBuilder;
```

These are the two lines of code I'm using to try and import it. I've downloaded the .jar files from the exp4j website however when I try and run these nothing happens. Is this library still in use and the downloadable version working?

Also is there anyway to install it without using the .jar files from the website? Can it be installed from Git?

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Ben

edit:

I have added the following to my dependencies but the exp4j variables are still not recognised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working...

Adding the dependencies in and removing the imports from my main sorted it out after reloading my project.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following steps to add exp4j in your android studio project.

- Download exp4j binary jar from the official site. [Download](http://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/exp4j-0.4.8.jar)
- Import exp4j into android studio by copying the jar files in app/libs folder.
- Add the following line in your module build.gradle file dependencies.

  ```
  dependencies {
      implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      ...
  }
  ```